# How to hide system information when using dhcpcd?

Tags: linux, security, dhcp, dhcpcd

I'm using `dhcpcd` to obtain an IP address on a laptop via WiFi. After logging in to the router, I noticed that it knows too much about my system:

```
Host Name:      hostname
Device Type:    dhcpcd-6.11.3:Linux-4.8.4-1-ARCH:x86_64:GenuineIntel
IP Address:     192.168.1.100
MAC Address:    aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
...
```

Can I hide the 'Device Type' in dhcpcd, or supply something more general?

Answer (score 1):

Lookup "DHCP Fingerprinting". I'm sure it's possible to turn off some of what your client reports to the DHCP server but some of it looks critical to normal operation of DHCP.

When searching for information on the subject, make sure you look for settings on the client side, not the server side.